# Symfony2, createQueryBuilder count one to many relationship

Tags: symfony, count, query-builder

I have 2 entities linked by a one to many relation.
Recruitment and Candidat
You may have many candidats for one recruitment.

I want to list all recruitment and count how many candidat each recruitment has.

I use the recruitment repository and put the code:

```
public function myFindAllRecruitment()
{
  $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r');
  $qb->select('r');
  $qb->Join('r.candidat', 'c');
  $qb->addSelect("COUNT(c.id) as candidatCount");
  $qb->groupBy('r.id');


 $qb->orderBy('r.id', 'DESC');

  return $qb
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
  ;
}
```

In my RecruitmentController I have:

```
$listRecruitment = $repository->myFindAllRecruitment();
```

In my TWIG view something like:

```
{% for recruitment in listRecruitment %}

            <tr>
                {#(this is line 48)#}<td>{{ recruitment.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ recruitment.titleFr }}</td>
                <td>{{ recruitment.locationFr }}</td>......
```

And I get this error:
"Key "id" for array with keys "0, candidatCount" does not exist in MyBundle:Recruitment:index.html.twig at line 48"

If someone knows what wrong with my query it will be nice.
Thank you

Comment: Notice that I tried join and leftJoin in the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thank you, I found the solution.
It was in the TWIG render:

Objects were accessible with [0] and [1] or ['candidatCount'] for the the count

Code exemple:

```
{% for recruitment in listRecruitment %}

            <tr>
                <td>{{ recruitment[0].id }}</td>
                <td>{{ recruitment[0].titleFr }}</td>
                <td>{{ recruitment[0].locationFr }}</td>
                <td>{{ recruitment[0].typePoste }}</td>
                <td>{{ recruitment[0].dateins|date('Y-m-d') | localizeddate('full', 'none') }}</td>
                <td>
                    {{ recruitment['candidatCount'] }}........
```

And the query was good.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So you have this Candidat entity like this

```
......
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Recruitment", inversedBy="candidates")
*/
$recruitment;
....
```

Then your query should look like this:

```
   public function myFindAllRecruitment()
    {
      $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r');
      $qb->select('r');
         ->addSelect('(SELECT count(c) FROM PATHTO\Bundle\Entity\Candidat as c WHERE c.rectuitment = r.id group by c.rectuitment) as count)');
         ->orderBy('r.id', 'DESC');

      return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

you will get output like this:

```
[
  0 => [
   'rectuitment' => ...Object,
   'count'=> ...,
   ...

]
```